# CSharpCodeProvider compile exception

Tags: c#, compilation, csharpcodeprovider

My program often compile c#-code and sometimes i got a ArgumentException like "The file name 'C:\Users--\AppData\Local\Temp\wvpc3m5m.0.cs' was already in the collection. Parameter name: fileName".

Settings of compiler is next:

```
public void Init()
{
    this.compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters
    {
        GenerateExecutable = false,
        GenerateInMemory = true
    };
}
```

Compilation:

```
public CompilerResults Compile(String code)
{
    CompilerResults result = this.codeProvider
        .CompileAssemblyFromSource(this.compilerParameters, code);

    return result;
}
```

I think that the codeProvider write passed string into a file, and sometimes he try to write in one and the same file twice.

Comment: There is no point in keeping the CodeProvider around.  Just create a fresh one with the *new* operator.

Comment: I do this, but exception keep throwing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that all CSharpCodeProvider's instance can compile the code once a time slot.
This code solve problem:

```
    private readonly Object lockCompile = new Object();
    public CompilerResults Compile(String code)
    {
        CompilerResults result = null;
        lock (lockCompile)
        {
            using (CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
            {
                result = codeProvider
                   .CompileAssemblyFromSource(this.compilerParameters, code);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```